# are there any way to implement VideoSampleAccess/AudioSampleAccess on private server

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, actionscript-3

VideoSampleAccess and AudioSampleAccess are configs provided in FMS and WOWZA servers, which allows flash to access BitmapData retrieved from NetStream to prevent SecurityError #2123.

Are there any standards to implement these two settings on a private server/environment.

Comment: What do you mean private server/environment? If you're implementing your own RTMP server, I'm guessing this would be trivial.

Comment: no, pure tcp retrieving data (custom protocol) and push into video object. any idea how to implement these two security option beside using rtmp?